# Change CSS style sheet directly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a unique situation here. I have several buttons in HTML:
[image: Buttons]
Normally they would look like the one on the left, but when I hover my mouse on them, they will animate and look like the right one.

I also added two color pickers which change the background and foreground respectively. (Both pickers effect the whole document as well as the buttons)

```js
// Background color changer
var allb = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < allb.length; i++) {
  allb[i].style.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
}

// Foreground color changer
var allf = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < allf.length; i++) {
  allf[i].style.color = focolor;
  allf[i].style.borderColor = focolor;
}
```

If I use both color pickers, then the animation will break and nothing will change when I hover hover the buttons. I understand why - the color pickers have a persisting effect on the style.

**Is there a way to directly change the CSS file**, or otherwise bypass this problem?

### My code

```css
.button {
    font-family: SF, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #4c56af;
    border: none;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
.button1 {
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: SF, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    color: black;
    border: 4px solid #4c56af;
}
  
.button1:hover {
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: SF, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #4c56af;
    color: white;
}
```

Each button would look roughly like this:

```html
<button type="button" onclick=func() class="button button1">Play</button>
```

Comment: How did you implement the animations? Only CSS or using JavaScript?
It would be better if you also shared your animation/transition code.

Comment: @amirhshahbazi I only used CSS for the animations. Please see the updated question for the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the list of rules contained in a stylesheet. You can do that by means of [StyleSheetList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList) and [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) interfaces.

Select the stylesheet in question:

```
const styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0] // Use the index for the stylesheet whose rules you want to modify
```

Insert the rules using the [`insertRule()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule):

```
const bgcolor = "green";
const focolor = "yellow";

styleSheet.insertRule(`
   button {
      background-color: ${bgcolor};
      color: ${focolor};
      border-color: ${focolor};
   }
`, styleSheet.cssRules.length);

styleSheet.insertRule(`
   button:hover {
      background-color: ${focolor};
      color: ${bgcolor};
   }
`, styleSheet.cssRules.length);
```

If you need, you can remove those rules afterwards through the [`deleteRule()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule).

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround.
Write your CSS animation code as a separate class, like this:

```
.button--animated {
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: SF, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #4c56af;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Then use the`mouseenter` event on all button elements for adding the transition class to it, and use the 'mouseleave' for removing it:

```
buttonElement.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    element.classList.add('button--animated')
});
buttonElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    element.classList.remove('button--animated')
});
```

If it doesn't work, add `!important` to the `button--animated` class's CSS. it's not ideal but may get the work done.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. However, how do I make it so that the CSS rule is changed for the `button--animated` class? Currently, when I hover my mouse on it, it still shows the blue (`#4c56af`) background.

Comment: You're welcome.
Can you share the full code? Maybe in a CodePen or something?

Comment: I think, the code I included is already sufficient. I imported the font called "SF" before.